Comparing unsupervised approaches to topic prevalence detection in semi-structured nested textual data
I am trying to understand approaches to (ideally, probabilistically) detecting the prevalence of latent topics in semi-structured, nested textual data. Specifically, there appear to be at least two approaches (described below) to using unsupervised learning/topic models for this task and I am wondering about the drawbacks/strengths of the two.
Example of "semi-structured, nested textual data"
Let's assume the data are a set of N reports about N different companies (parent-documents). Each report contains a set of bullet points (sub-documents), with each bullet consisting of 1-3 sentences - i.e., Tweet-length. If needed, we can assume each bullet point maps to 1 latent topic (e.g., the company's costs) but that topic can appear multiple times (using different words) within and across reports. Finally, the number and topics of bullet points varies across reports. Consequently, different reports often discuss similar topics but some may discuss more or unique topics.
Here's a toy data example with latent topics in parentheses:

And a quick chart showing that topics and # of bullets can vary across reports:

Approaches to identifying and detecting topics
Approach 1: Flatten data to one column per report then use reports as documents with multi-membership topic model
Example of data:


Concatenate all bullet points within a report so that each report contains a single, large paragraph of text.
Fit multi-label probabilistic model with prevalence parameter (e.g. structural topic model, BERTopic) to identify topics and prevalence.
Use topic prevalence parameters to assign reports to (one or more) topics.

Issue: topic prevalence is a probability simplex so e.g. a document that clearly contains 3 topics will assign probability of 0.33 to each and 0 to others. Prevalence thus only tells us which topics are most likely relative to other topics but doesn't tell us the absolute probability.
Approach 2: Make data long then use bullet-points as documents with company name as predictor of topic prevalence in multi-membership topic model
Example of data:


Pool all bullet points across all reports, such that a bullet point is treated as a document.
Fit topic model (e.g. STM) to the documents, using the company associated with the report (meta-data) as a topic prevalence covariate.
Use the coefficient for the association between a company and topic as a measure of the topic's relative prevalence.

Issue: the coefficients are all relative to the mean prevalence so you can only know some companies are more strongly correlated with a topic's prevalence...you won't know if a topic is mentioned in ALL reports.
